# identify shackle or swivel tensioner mechanism

Tags: mechanisms, threads

[image]

What is this called? I would say it is a shackle or I suppose, a turnbuckle, but it appears to have a right threaded rod on both sides and right threaded free nuts inside.

I would just say it's a shackle or maybe a swivel, but there are some really important design properties that aren't specified by that.  I want to say something that is usually about 5 to 1 length width aspect ratio, has a hole in both ends, has a wide berth for inserting and tightening free nuts and seems to have some kind of in the field bending and maneuverability capability.

[image: shackle_right]

[image: shackle_left]

Answer (score 1):

As only the right hand rod is threaded then tightening it (rotating clockwise looking from the left hand side) will increase the tension on the cable. All that appears to be needed is a bar that fits inside the turnbuckle.

The left hand rod is freely rotating in the metal body.

Edit:
The subsequent images seem to show examples that, imho, were put together (incorrectly...) from parts as available. If only one side is threaded then it works fine, if both sides are threaded then one has to be a left-hand thread otherwise it won’t shorten or lengthen the cable.

If both are righthand threads then you have to find a way of only turning one of the nuts while keeping the other stationary.

Comment: good catch.  I've added more pictures of the variations.

Comment: @AndyzSmith check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your Informed response.  With all that space in the open buckle can't you get a wrench in there or even a deep socket, that rod can only push in there 1.5 in or so.  Or is that why the thing is actually open on one end, to facilitate tightening.  No, it goes through holes in both open end pieces.